# How to get current offsets for all partitions for my consumer?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I am trying to get the current offsets for each partition available. According to the docs, [consumer.position](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html?highlight=offset#confluent_kafka.Consumer.position) should do the trick, so I tried like so:

```py
consumer = Consumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': config.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
    'group.id': config.CONSUMER_GROUP,
    'enable.auto.commit': False,
})

# get all topics
topics = consumer.list_topics()

# get all partitions
partitions = []
for name, meta  in topics.topics.items():
    for partition_id in meta.partitions.keys():
        part = TopicPartition(name, partition_id)
        partitions.append(part)

# get all offsets
x = consumer.position(partitions)
```

However, all the offsets in the resulting partitions in `x` are still `-1001`.

If I check with lenses or some other tool, I can see that this result is not correct, the consumer group I'm unsing has consumed messages and committed them to Kafka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, this is the solution that worked:

```py
consumer = Consumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': config.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
    'group.id': config.CONSUMER_GROUP,
    'enable.auto.commit': False,
})

# get all topics
topics = consumer.list_topics()

# get all partitions
partitions = []
for name, meta  in topics.topics.items():
    for partition_id in meta.partitions.keys():
        part = TopicPartition(name, partition_id)
        partitions.append(part)

# get last committed offsets
partitions = consumer.committed(partitions)
```

Apparently `consumer.position` does not work as advertised, but `consumer.committed` returns the stored offsets, even when the consumer is currently not subscribed to a topic/partition.

Answer (score 1):

Trying adding `consumer.subscribe()` or `consumer.assign()` function

```
consumer = Consumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': config.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS,
    'group.id': config.CONSUMER_GROUP,
    'enable.auto.commit': False,
})

# get all partitions
partitions = []
for name, meta  in topics.topics.items():
    for partition_id in meta.partitions.keys():
        part = TopicPartition(name, partition_id)
        partitions.append(part)

consumer.assign(partitions)
committed = consumer.committed(tp)

last_offset = consumer.position(tp)
print("topic: %s partition: %s committed: %s last: %s lag: %s" % (TOPIC, p, committed, last_offset))
```

Comment: What is the difference between committed and position? According to the docs they should both return the last committed offset.

Comment: position will return the last consumed offset+1.

Comment: So for some reason only committed works, position does not return the proper offsets. Committed works also without consumer.assign.

Comment: any specific error with position or is it still -1001?

Comment: position returns -1001 for all offsets in the above example